# Kotlin: mutableMap doesn't recognise put()

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, mutable

This is part of a recipe app. I am in the Recipe class which I have written. Ingredient is another class I have written. The idea is to store the ingredient and its amount (as an Int) in a map.

In the class body I have declared the map as:

```
var ingredients: Map<Ingredient, Int>
```

And in the init{} body:

```
ingredients = mutableMapOf<Ingredient, Int>()
```

Here is the problem - this function is to add an ingredient. It updates the quantity if the ingredient is already in the map. the put()method should do this but Android Studio is turning it red, and when I mouse over the word 'put' it says 'Unresolved reference: put'. The plus symbol also has a red underline. I thought this was a basic part of the mutable map. Where have I gone wrong? (Don't worry - there will be an 'else' part!)

```
fun addIngredientAndAmount(ingredient: Ingredient, quantity: Int) {
    if (ingredients.containsKey(ingredient)) {
        val oldQuantity = ingredients[ingredient]
        ingredients.put(ingredient, oldQuantity + quantity)
    }
}
```

Comment: You marked the property as a `Map`, not as a `MutableMap`. Even though the underlying object happens to be mutable, the compiler only sees the property type. But why would you initialize the property in a separate `init` block?

Comment: We are initialising some other stuff in the init block so it seems a little neater. Also, this is our first time using Kotlin for a project and we are a little more used to Java. For context, this is a group project as part of a masters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `ingredients` is declared as `Map`, but `Map` represents a read-only interface so it has no `put` which is a function of `MutableMap`. It doesn't matter if you initialize it as `MutableMap`, because the compiler checks the type you specified for the variable.

You should declare it as:

```
var ingredients: MutableMap<Ingredient, Int>
```

You can also initialize it in place instead of using the `init` block:

```
var ingredients: MutableMap<Ingredient, Int> = mutableMapOf<Ingredient, Int>()
```

If you do so you can also avoid stating the type explicitly, as the compiler will automatically infer it.

```
var ingredients = mutableMapOf<Ingredient, Int>()
```

or

```
var ingredients: MutableMap<Ingredient, Int> = mutableMapOf()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I tried it before and it turned red, so I imagine I misspelled it or something. Silly. However, the plus is still underlined in red - I just want to add two ints together. Is it really necessary to put that in a single variable before using it in the put() method?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by adding !! after ingredients[ingredient]

Comment: I also recommend making it a `val`. Using a read-write property for a mutable collection is kind of error-prone because it can be changed in two different ways. There are cases where you potentially would need that flexibility, but they should be rare.

Comment: @Donagh `!!` is a code smell — a sign that there might be [an underlying problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), and that there's often a better way.  In this case, you could get the existing value from the map, and if it's not null then update it.  One concise way might be: `ingredients[ingredient]?.let{ ingredients[ingredient] = it + quantity }`…

Comment: …though from the method name I suspect your `else` part would be setting a value for new ingredients too.  You could do both together in one line: `ingredients[ingredient] = (ingredients[ingredient] ?: 0) + quantity`.

Comment: Oh is that called something like an Elvis statement? I've seen it before. Thanks for the tip!